# How to compare multiple columns with other table in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-redshift

I have below mentioned two tables:

Table1:

```
ID        Value1      Value2       Value3     Remarks
RTE-10    2400.00     1.5          2300       Processed
RTE-11    1300.00     1.8          1750       Failed
RTE-12    1900.00     1.25         2000       Accepted
```

Table2:

```
ID        Read1      Read2         Read3         Status
RTE-10    2400.0     1.5           2300.25       Processed
RTE-11    1300.0     1.4           1900.22       Accepted
RTE-12    1600.0     1.20          2000.45       Processed
```

By comparing both the tables, I want to fetch those rows where values are not matching from `Table1` to `Table2` (Ignore the decimal values).

Required Output:

```
ID       Value1      Value2       Value3     Remarks    Read1      Read2         Read3         Status
RTE-11   1300.00     1.8          1750       Failed     1300.0     1.4           1900.22       Accepted
RTE-12   1900.00     1.25         2000       Accepted   1600.0     1.20          2000.45       Processed
```

I am trying below mentioned query:

```
select * from Table1 t1
left join Table2 t2 on t1.ID=t2.ID
where t1.Value1!=t2.Read1
and t1.Value2!=t2.Read2
and t1.Value3!=t2.Read3
and t1.Remarks!=t2.Status
group by t1.ID;
```

Comment: you forgot to add your attempt. please edit your question adding it

Comment: You may be looking for truncate function https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `CAST` as `UNSIGNED` to ignore the decimal values be joining condition.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE Table1(
    ID VARCHAR(50),
    Value1 FLOAT,
    Value2 FLOAT,
    Value3 FLOAT,
    Remarks VARCHAR(50)
);


INSERT INTO Table1 values ('RTE-10',2400.00,1.5,2300,'Processed');
INSERT INTO Table1 values ('RTE-11',1300.00,1.8,1750,'Failed');
INSERT INTO Table1 values ('RTE-12',1900.00,1.25,2000,'Accepted');

CREATE TABLE Table2(
    ID VARCHAR(50),
    Read1 FLOAT,
    Read2 FLOAT,
    Read3 FLOAT,
    Status VARCHAR(50)
);


INSERT INTO Table2 values ('RTE-10',2400.0,1.5,2300.25,'Processed');
INSERT INTO Table2 values ('RTE-11',1300.0,1.4,1900.22,'Accepted');
INSERT INTO Table2 values ('RTE-12',1600.0,1.20,2000.45,'Processed');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.*
FROM Table1 t1 JOIN Table2 t2 
ON t1.ID = t2.ID and 
(
    CAST(t1.Value1 AS UNSIGNED )<> CAST(t2.Read1 AS UNSIGNED ) OR
    CAST(t1.Value2 AS UNSIGNED )<> CAST(t2.Read2 AS UNSIGNED ) OR
    CAST(t1.Value3 AS UNSIGNED )<> CAST(t2.Read3 AS UNSIGNED )
 );

| ID     | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 | Remarks  | ID     | Read1 | Read2 | Read3   | Status    |
| ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | -------- | ------ | ----- | ----- | ------- | --------- |
| RTE-11 | 1300   | 1.8    | 1750   | Failed   | RTE-11 | 1300  | 1.4   | 1900.22 | Accepted  |
| RTE-12 | 1900   | 1.25   | 2000   | Accepted | RTE-12 | 1600  | 1.2   | 2000.45 | Processed |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ptMnHFwJ1umeeQ3cFYUtzT/0)

Comment: Sorry using Redshift, Is there any alternative of 'unsinged' in redshift.

Comment: You can try to use `cast(column as integer)` in redshitf ...@Jupiter